# Mathematical expression in axis label

Tags: r, plot, latex, axis-labels, plotmath

In R, I use `expression(theta[l])` so that the label of my plot axis is that same as `$\theta_l$` from LaTeX. For esthetic reasons, I'd rather like to display `$\theta_\ell$`. Can you help me?

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Before, I did

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab=expression(theta[l]))
```

and I exported the resulting picture in pdf. Then, using

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=.6]{test.pdf}}
\end{figure}
```

my picture was inserted in LaTeX.

Following the comments, here is what I now do:

```
require(tikzDevice)
tikz("test.tex", standAlone=TRUE, width=5, height=5)

plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab="$\\theta_\\ell$")

dev.off()
tools::texi2pdf('test.tex')
system(paste(getOption('pdfviewer'),'test.pdf'))
```

However, when I insert the resuling plot in LaTeX, the quality of the figure is not as good as before. Is there something more that I can do?

Comment: @agstudy: Windows. Linux is also fine for me.

Comment: @Sven Hohenstein: Thanks for your picture :-)

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190087/italic-greek-letters-latex-style-math-in-plot-titles/8190537#8190537) what you're looking for?

Comment: @plannapus: mmmmm, interesting ! I will investigate that package :-)

Comment: This works with `cairo_pdf`: `plot(1:10, main = "\u2113")`. edit: I just realized that you want theta_ell, that wont probably help there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is really no reason to use a [possibly unmaintained package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/index.html) like 'tikzDevice' for such a simple problem.  Part of the problem with the 'tikz' device is that it doesn't seem to correctly accept the 'xpinch' and 'ypinch' arguments that specify your plot's resolution.

There is a larger question of adding LaTEX notation to plots, but for this localized problem, the question is one of specifying the font to make the base 'plotmath' package display cursive letters for you.

You can change the font for your x-axis label by separating it out from the plot command and choosing a custom font from within the 'title' function with something like this:

```
plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab="")
windowsFonts(script=windowsFont("Script MT Bold"))
title(xlab=expression(theta[l]), family="script")
```

What we've done is to specify a null label for the x-axis in the plot command to first make space.  Then, we load up a system font into the available font families (I like Script MT Bold for expressions).  Finally, we can use the 'title' function to plot the x-axis label and specify the family for any text in that label.

By doing this, we preserve all of the original functionality of the plotting device, so you should no longer have a drop in resolution when converting to PDF.

[image: demo of chart]

Now if anyone has a good solution to the LaTEX notation problem outside of the 'tikzDevice' package, I would love to hear about it.  The only way I know to do this well is to flip the model and use the 'tikz' LaTEX package to draw the whole graphic manually from within the LaTEX file or to use the 'pixmap' R package to draw an image of my expression on top of the plot.  Neither feels like a perfect approach.

Comment: Where do we find the "windowsFonts"?

Comment: These are the fonts installed on your system.  You just have to use the name of the font as it is registered on your computer.  On a Windows computer, you can use the Character Map application (system tool).

Comment: `windowsFonts` is a function that can display the currently avaialble font mappings for the interactive graphics device, and it can be used to assign new mappings. It's obviously only avaialble on ... Windows. There are corresponding functions on Mac (`quartzFonts`) and Nix ("`X11Fonts`).

Comment: I think it's under maintenance. It had been updated at 2015-01-07 when I checked.

Answer (score 3):

I think `tikzDevice` *is* the way to go here. You can install from `R-forge`.

```
install.packages("tikzDevice", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

The tikz /pgf philosophy is to create a plot that can be typeset. You will probably want these to be consistent with your document. Eg, with the same packages, fonts, font size etc

You can set these things within a call to `tikz` by setting

options such as the document declaration

```
options(tikzDocumentDeclaration = "\\documentclass[10pt]{article}")
```

packages

`tikzLatexPackages` (or similar)

You can also control the font size.

All these things are detailed in

?tikzDevice.

---

You could also use `knitr` to create your plots within a  literate programming document (.rnw)

In this case, using a tikz device a pdf is created (as external = TRUE), using the same document declaration and header / packages as the whole document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}

<<setup, include = FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(dev = 'tikz', external = TRUE)
@


<<myplot, fig.width=5, fig.height = 5, echo=FALSE>>=
plot(1:10, 1:10, xlab="$\\theta_\\ell$")
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are installing on a Mac (or Windows) you will probably need to install the proper package of tools and use: `install.packages("tikzDevice", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")`

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat dirty solution, but it makes it:

```
plot(1,1, xlab=expression(theta))
title(xlab="    \u2113",line=3.2,cex.lab=.7)
```

First plot with the theta symbol. Then add the \ell symbol with smaller font size and manually setting the position.

[image]

Comment: @carelus: Thanks. Does it still appear as \ell when the image is exported in pdf format?

Comment: just checked and apparently it doesn't :-(

Comment: The behavior will depend on the font mappings of the pdf-viewer. On a Mac using the Preview.app as viewer it does appear with the same cursive-ell. Your viewer need to have a proper Symbol font to get the same behavior and I believe the Windows viewers are often not set up properly for this.

Comment: @Dwin: Thanks for the precision. Do you have a recommendation regarding the pdf-viewer on windows?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround [here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/R/PDF/pdfEncoding.html). They do explain a lengthy process to get the encoding to work with the standard pdf device. Otherwise, the CairoPDF device can be used by installing the [Cairo](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cairo/index.html) package. Then something like `xlab="\u2113"` will show up in the pdf using @Julián Urbano's solution. I had no luck using the character within an expression.