# Writing a special expression in R including using LaTeX calligraphic fonts

Tags: r, plot

How can I write

```
$\mathcal{O}$(LaTeX code)
```

in legend of a plot in R?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480082/r-plot-mathematical-expression-in-axis-label) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395105/getting-latex-into-r-plots) for instance.

Comment: I can not install the package "tikzDevice" in R 2.15.2

Comment: @user2227801 **tikzdevice** was removed from CRAN. You can install versions by hand from the archive: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/index.html

Comment: I tried but I couldn't install this package. Is there another way?

Comment: What do you mean that you couldn't install the package?  Did it give errors?  Do you just not know how?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Latex but if the code you gave is supposed to give the "big O" used in mathematics then `expression(Omicron)` should be equivalent.

Comment: Yes, the error is:Error in read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In unzip(zipname, exdir = dest) : error 1 in extracting from zip file
2: In read.dcf(file.path(pkgname, "DESCRIPTION"), c("Package", "Type")) :
  cannot open compressed file 'tikzDevice_0.6.2.tar.gz/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: `expression(Omicron)` is not `mathcal(O)`.

Comment: You will have to build the package by hand. If you're on Windows, you'll need a toolchain (Linux and OSX have it prepacked). Search "how to build r package".