# In R plots, how to have symbol for the set of real numbers with font similar to LaTeX's \mathbb?

Tags: r, plot, fonts, latex, plotmath

Here is what I am trying to achieve.

When designing a plot in R-project, I would like to include in the plot's legend/axes the "R" symbol for the set of real numbers with font similar to that of LaTeX's `\mathbb` command (i.e. the stylized way to write uppercase letters when referring to sets of real numbers, natural numbers, etc).

Would that be possible to achieve somehow? I found [older questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480082/mathematical-expression-in-axis-label?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) on how to use OS fonts in parts of R plots, but this alone does not solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried tikzDevice (cf https://stackoverflow.com/a/8190537/8416610) together with the mathbb LaTeX package?

Comment: You can use the stringi package to directly call unicode characters. `library(stringi)
stri_unescape_unicode(paste0("\\u","211D"))`

Comment: You can use the unicode symbol directly. However, I found I needed to use the Symbola font to get the symbol to render properly (an empty box appeared with other fonts). For example: `library(ggplot2); ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt, colour=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x="Where x \U2208 \U211d", colour="\u211d") +
  theme(text=element_text(family="Symbola"))`.

Comment: On my Linux system I can use the Unicode code point directly `plot(1, 1, xlab = "\u211D")`.

Comment: So did this work?